# how to make a my method that is using Wait.Until ignore throwing exceptions in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i have a method that is

```
private boolean findElements(
                                  String xpath,
                                  int timeOut ) {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, timeOut );

        try {
            if( wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.xpath( xpath ) ) ) != null ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch( NoSuchElementException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

it returning true when element is found but it throwing an exception when element is not found, how can i make the method returning false instead of the exception throwing , or is there a better way or method that is boolean which can do the job for me.

Kind Regards

Comment: I think you don't even need the "else" block.. just catch the exception, don't even print it... return false

Comment: Did you try catching a TimeoutException rather than a NoSuchElementException?

Comment: yes you right, i don't even need the else the code never get to the else argument,and yes Jae i have tried the timeoutException , the problem is that the if condition i wrote will never return null because it's basically throw an exception when the element is not found. i am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the purpose of the method.

Comment: @AliHamadi I imagine that `try { wait.until( ... ); return true; } catch(TimeoutException ex) { return false; }` might work if the `wait.until( ... )` throws a TimeoutException reporting that no elements have been found.

Comment: Thank You So Much Jae!!! it worked , to be honest i am not that good at throwing exceptions error and how they work, i was thinking that each method throw a specific exception error that i can't change and i thought the NoSuchElementException is the only one that i could use, thank you very much Jae

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jae Heon Lee answered this question

```
try {
    wait.until( ... );
    return true;
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    // might work if the wait.until( ... ) throws a TimeoutException 
    // reporting that no elements have been found. 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to catch a WebDriverTimeoutException