# findElements() returns NoSuchElementException instead of returning empty list

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Following is code :

```
List<WebElement> listOfAllMatchingElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[last()]"))
```

OR

```
 List<WebElement> listOfAllMatchingElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[5]"))
```

Now as per my understanding, this should return list of Web elements Or an empty list[Considering the xpath is syntactically correct].

Instead, an exception[NoSuchElementException] is thrown with a confusing message as "returned an unexpected error".
Following is the exception,

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Finding elements with xpath == .//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[5]returned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.37 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'OTINWISRCDT050', ip: '172.24.187.38', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[5]}
Session ID: a45d6015-f529-4e85-924e-3214076d59e8
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:31736/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

The code used for element wait is like,

```
public boolean customElementWaitWithTimeoutWithProperties(WebDriver UtilDriver,By locatorWithLocation,int Timeout)
{
    WebDriver driver = UtilDriver;
    boolean elementFound=false;

    int i=1;
    try
    {

        while(i<=Timeout )
        {
            if(((Boolean.compare(elementFound,false)))==0)
            {


                List<WebElement> listOfAllMatchingElements = driver.findElements(locatorWithLocation);
                if(!(listOfAllMatchingElements.isEmpty()) && (((Boolean.compare(elementFound,false)))==0))
                {
                    if(listOfAllMatchingElements.size()>1)
                    {
                        log.info("Common Methods :customElementWaitWithTimeout: More than one element is found for given location, check the location !!");

                        elementFound=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(listOfAllMatchingElements.size()==1 && (((Boolean.compare(elementFound,false)))==0))
                    {


                        log.info("Common Methods :customElementWaitWithTimeout: Element  found on "+i+" attempt !!");
                        elementFound=true;


                        break;

                    }
                }
                else if ((listOfAllMatchingElements.isEmpty()))
                {

                    log.info("Common Methods :customElementWaitWithTimeout: Element  is not found on "+i+" attempt!!");

                }
                Thread.sleep(1200);
            }
            i=i+1;
        }


    }
    catch(Exception elementFoundCheck)
    {
        log.error("Common Methods[customElementWaitWithTimeout]: Exception caught !!");
        elementFoundCheck.printStackTrace();
    }

    return elementFound;
}
```

[Additional info]However,

when i put a hard wait for certain time[To make sure element is loaded] & write as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[5]")).click();
```

The element is getting clicked.

Any reason/solution for the problem ??[findElements() returning NoSuchElementException]

Comment: Why are you writing custom wait.When there is Explicit wait already implemented in Selenium

Comment: Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve As your question stands, it is going to get closed as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: The code here is complex, confusing and unreadable. Please trim it down to the actual issue.

Comment: @Arran Which part of the question you find complex/confusing/unreadable ??   The Title of the question clears the point i'm trying to ask, the exact statement where the exception is thrown is given clearly, the complete exception is also given.Finally the complete code is also given[which is a simple generic method checking availability of webElement using findElements() ] where the problematic code statement is placed.   It'll be great if you could suggest edits if any rather than throwing some generic comment!!

Answer (score 3):

Update

Why are you reinventing the wheel by writing your own wait algorithm when it's [already](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) there. [Refer](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

```
  //wait for 20 seconds 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    List<WebElement> listOfAllMatchingElements=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[last()]")));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, its copy paste mistake. I'll correct it. You can refer the element wait code that i've share for details.

Comment: I tried your solution & its not working this way. Then i tried waiting for single element & it worked.    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[last()]")))

Comment: This has put me in more confusion as i cant think of the reason as to why the looking for multiple elements not working . . !!!

Comment: Its thowing an exception  [org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Finding elements with xpath == .//*[@id='e1MMenuRoot']/div/div[5]returned an unexpected error]    & not returning any value.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680295/how-to-make-a-my-method-that-is-using-wait-until-ignore-throwing-exceptions-in-s/25810781#25810781)